# Populate RecyclerView from Firestore async call

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, coroutine

I'm able to retrieve data from Firestore (it is definetly available inside the GlobalScope of `populateValletList()` and I was able to populate my RecyclerView from an asnyc database call or when I simply added a `Vallet` to my items list manually inside `populateValletList()`, however, when I want to populate that View from Firestore data it doesn't work. The

onBindViewHolder in RecyclerAdapter doesn't get called anymore

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when(holder){
        is ValletViewHolder ->{
            holder.bind(items[position])
        }
    }
}
```

that's how I populate my items `private var items : MutableList<Vallet> = ArrayList()` :

```
fun populateValletList() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        items = getAllValletsFromDatabase.executeUseCase()
    }
}
```

I init my RecyclerView inside onActivityCreated

```
private fun initRecyclerView(){
    recycler_view_vallets.apply{
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        addItemDecoration(ValletRecyclerAdapter.ValletItemDecorator(30))
        valletAdapter = ValletRecyclerAdapter()
        adapter = walletAdapter
    }
    valletAdapter.populateValletList()
}
```

This is my first time working with coroutines, what am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think there is some improvements that you could in your code, but the reason I believe is not working the way you want is because I you update your Items List, you have to call *notifyDataSetChanged()* on your adapter.

Ideally u should run ur coroutine using a scope that is not global, to avoid leaks, you can use a viewmodel for it, or you could use *lifecycleScope.run {  }* in ur fragment, for that I believe you will need to add a depedency.

```
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

And regarding update your recycler, I recommend using ListAdapter, so it adds DIFF Utils and makes easier to update values.

To sum up.

Ur Recycler Adapter would be like this:

```
class HomePatchesAdapter : ListAdapter<Vallet, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(REPO_COMPARATOR) {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return HomePatchesViewHolder.create(parent, viewType)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val repoItem = getItem(position)


        if (repoItem != null) {
            (holder as HomePatchesViewHolder).bind(repoItem)
        }
    }


    companion object {
        private val REPO_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Vallet>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Vallet, newItem: Vallet): Boolean =
                oldItem.name == newItem.name

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Vallet, newItem: Vallet): Boolean =
                oldItem == newItem
        }
    }


}
```

and ur fragment would be like this:

```
private fun initRecyclerView(){
    recycler_view_vallets.apply{
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        addItemDecoration(ValletRecyclerAdapter.ValletItemDecorator(30))
    }

        val adapter = HomePatchesAdapter()
        recycler_view_vallets?.adapter = adapter

    lifecycleScope.run {

      adapter.submitList(getAllValletsFromDatabase.executeUseCase())

     } 

}
```

Let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: I had a few minutes to try out notifyDataSetChanged() and it worked. I'll later read into your suggestion with using a ListAdapter and figure how that works, when I have more spare time.

Comment: Glady I could help :)